# How can I draw a sprite in it's own class?

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, sprite

I'm trying to program a game with a friend, and I'm very confused as to how to draw sprites. I can draw code in my Game1 class, below.

```
namespace SweetGeorgiaBrown
{
    /// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
            enum GameStates { TitleScreen, Overworld, Menu, Battle, GameOver };
    GameStates gameState = GameStates.Battle;
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    Texture2D dinoTex;
    Texture2D alienTex;
    Texture2D robotTex;
    Texture2D eroboTex;
    SpriteFont basic;


    private Vector2 textLocation = new Vector2(20, 20);
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


    }

    public class Health
    {
        public static int dinoHP = 300;
        public static int alienHP = 200;
        public static int robotHP = 100;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        dinoTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Sprites\dino\dinoFrontOvwld");
        alienTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Sprites\alien\alienFrontOvwld");
        robotTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Sprites\robot\robotFrontOvwld");
        eroboTex = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Sprites\robo1\robo1OvwldFront");

        basic = Content.Load<SpriteFont>(@"Fonts\Basic");
        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameStates.Battle:
                break;
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        if ((gameState == GameStates.Battle))
        {
            spriteBatch.DrawString(
                basic,
                "ASDFASDFADFASDFA ", textLocation, Color.Black);
            spriteBatch.Draw(
                dinoTex, textLocation, Color.White);
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

In my Game1 code, I can successfully draw that sprite and the text there on the screen. However, I want to draw a sprite in another class, but I have absolutely no idea what to put there.

In the other class, I wish I could just do something as simple as

sprite.Draw(//here would be x and y coords of where the sprite goes, name of the texture), and have that be it, but it seems to just not work that way. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does indeed work like that. Extract your sprite specific code into a class that is structured something similar to:

```
public Sprite()
{
}

public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
}

public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
{
}
```

Then in your game1 class you can call

```
Sprite.Update(gameTime);
```

and

```
Sprite.Draw(spriteBatch);
```

That should help you get started. Did you try some approaches yourself, if so post them and we can see where they went wrong, or are you just hoping for a quick answer you can copy and paste?

Comment: I deleted most of them because they didn't work, but I tried doing something like Game1.Draw(spritename), or a lengthier attempt was where I tried to write my own Draw code, but I didn't include an Update, and so that didn't work either. Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: Still incredibly confused as to what I should be ding right now. I made a class called SpriteDraw, and in it I have public SpriteDraw(
            Vector2 location,
            Texture2D texture)
        {
            
        }
        public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
        }
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
        }

I don't know where in Game1 I should be putting SpiteDraw.Draw(spriteBatch); and SpriteDraw.Update(gameTime), because it's been giving me an error every time. I tried putting it in LoadContent by typing in

Comment: spriteDraw = new SpriteDraw(              
                new Vector2(0, 30),
                 new Texture2D"@/Sprites/dino/dinobackOvwld.png"
                     ));

but that doesn't seem to work either

Comment: I don't know how to get it to display a sprite though. Do I just call it through another class that isn't SpriteDraw? In LoadContent, I put 

spriteDraw = new SpriteDraw(
                textLocation,
                 robotTex);

I put spriteDraw.Draw(spriteBatch) in the 'if((gameState = GameStates.Battle))' code, and I put the update code underneath 'case GameStates.Battle:'

Comment: Derive your sprite from GameObject

Comment: What you are saying you've done sounds corret Josh. Are you positive that the gamestate does in fact equal Battle? If you've verified that this is in fact matching up maybe you could upload a zip of the project and I could look at it? I'd be much more helpful if I could see the debugger working it's magic.

Comment: Yes, gamestates is equal to Battle. I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong here. Here's the zip;

http://www.mediafire.com/?89ds4r8f4lr4je9

Comment: Sorry for the delay, totally forgot to check the code before now. I can tell you exactly why your spritedraw doesn't actually draw anything. Because it is an empty class. You never took your sprite specific code out of game1 and into spritedraw like I mentioned before.

The SpriteDraw class requires an object to hold the texture and another object to hold a position. These are assigned to in the constructor (this is why you pass two objects from game1 to spritedraw. 

From there insert the position update code into the spritedraw update and draw specific code into spritedraws draw method.

Comment: I'm still very very confused as to what to put in the SpriteDraw Draw method. I don't see anything in my Game1 that looks like specific code that would work. Should I be putting a loadcontent in my SpriteDraw? Would I be able to reference SpriteDraw in other methods without putting sprite specific code in there as well? I just don't know what exactly I'm supposed to be doing here.

Comment: I've decided to go about another way using XNA, but thank you for all your effort.

Comment: The second half of my reply was the specific content you need inside your spritedraw class. something like
Texture2D tex; 
Vector2 vec;

Then inside the constructor
tex = texture (the parameter)
vec = vector(the parameter)

Then your update changes the variable vec, and your draw uses spritebatch to draw tex and position vec. Does that help? I'm trying to not give specific code because of limited characters and better learning.