# SpriteBatch becoming null when passed? / Drawing a sprite in a different class?

Tags: c#, .net, xna, draw, xna-4.0

**Before marking this as a duplicate question, please read it.**

Derived from this:
[How can I draw a sprite in it's own class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284043/)

On the aforementioned question, Jonathan helped me to do this and I solved my original problem. But I wanted to know something else and I didn't have enough rep to comment, so I started up a new question.

---

So I have an XNA game which I want to add hit numbers to (hit numbers are little numbers that appear for a second when something gets damaged) but I'm struggling to with it. My `EnemyTest` class has an int called `Damage`. This is passed to the `Player` class when they collide so the player knows how much to health take off. But then I need to pass it once more to the `HitNumbers` class to display that number in a `DrawString`.

My problem is that I have a `Draw()` method in `HitNumbers` which takes `SpriteBatch spriteBatch` (for the `DrawString()` and `int Damage` for the number to display. But the `Player` class sends the `Damage` value to the main class then the main class passes that and it's `SpriteBatch` to `HitNumbers` which throws a NullReferenceException (apparently the Spritebatch is null, **but how can it be null when it's drawing all the other sprites?**)
But I'm a bit confused, I am aware that something incorrect is staring me in the face but I just can't see it. It's like putting your finger really close to your eye and trying to focus on it. Maybe my brain isn't in the right mood, but I'm hoping someone can help me.

### Relevant Part of `HitNumbers`

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, int damage)
{
    // print 'sbnull' to console if received spritebatch is null
    if(spriteBatch == null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sbnull");
    }

    spriteBatch.DrawString(RPG.font, EnemyTest.Damage.ToString(), RPG.hn.PlayerPos, Color.Red);  
}
```

### Relevant Part of `Player`

```
public void Damage(int damage)
{
    Health -= damage;

    main.showHitNumber(damage);
}
```

### Relevant Part of `RPG` (main class)

```
public void showHitNumber(int damage)
{
    hn.Draw(spriteBatch, damage);
}
```

Comment: Insert a break point in the code and step through it to see if everything is as you expect. Maybe, `Player` has a different instance of `RPG`. You might also consider making the sprite batch a game service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a beginner at XNA so I'm not even sure what a Game Service does or how to create one. I'll research it later. And I'll ste through it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have two spritebatch, and you are passing the one it's not initialized.

In this code:

```
public void showHitNumber(int damage)
{
    hn.Draw(spriteBatch, damage);
}
```

Put the cursor over "spriteBatch" and click with right mouse button, and select "Search all references". This will show wehre you are using that spritebacth instance.

You will have two situations:

1. That spritebatch instance is never initialized.
2. Is initialized, but the method that initialize it, is never called.

Comment: Okay so how would I use the instance that I want then?

Comment: Being sure that you are using a initialized instance. You can declare a global static instance or you could pass the spritebatch instance used to draw player =>  main.showHitNumber(spritebatch, damage);